# One char is not getting replaced with another using .replace() method

Tags: jquery, json, replace

```
[
 {
    "1": "${monthNumber:1,monthName:January}#",
    "2": "${monthNumber:2,monthName:February}#",
    "3": "${monthNumber:3,monthName:March}#",
    "4": "April",
    "5": "${monthNumber:5,monthName:May}#",
    "6": "${monthNumber:6,monthName:June}#",
    "7": "${monthNumber:7,monthName:July}#",
    "8": "${monthNumber:8,monthName:August}#",
    "9": "${monthNumber:9,monthName:Septemeber}#",
    "10": "${monthNumber:10,monthName:October}#",
    "11": "${monthNumber:11,monthName:November}#",
    "12": "${monthNumber:12,monthName:December}#"
  }
]
```

I am trying to remove all $ with [ and # with ]; But I don't know why `.replace` method is not replacing the supposed items.

I am using `.replace` as

```
JSON.stringify($scope.monthA).replace(/$/g, "[").replace(/#/g, "]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` character in a regex signifies the end of a string. If you want to actually replace that character in your text you need to escape it with a backslash `\`, so that the regex knows it's the actual character you're looking for.

```
JSON.stringify($scope.monthA).replace(/\$/g, "[").replace(/#/g, "]");
```

Comment: what is I want to replace "$ with [ and #" with ]?? You might get a clue here that I am trying to achieve structure of JSON :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that and I answered your question. I just explained _why_ it didn't work in addition to the correct code. Have you tried my code yet?

Comment: Yah Your code worked.and I solve my problem with replace(/"\$/g, "[").replace(/#"/g, "]"); Thanks :)